# NSDATA writeToFile crashes without a reason

Tags: objective-c, ipad, crash, nsdata, writetofile

I am downloading images from a url using NSDATA and saving them to local file system using

```
NSData *dataForStorage = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)];


    BOOL saveResult=[ dataForStorage writeToFile:jpegFilePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Write returned error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

My app crashes randomly without even giving a message, though some files are saved (again randomly). When I run the app in Debug mode, I frequently see "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" but continuing execution succeeds in saving some of the files.

This code is executed in background from:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) withObject:arr];
```

Please suggest.

Comment: can you post the crash log and the console log please?

Comment: Is it an iPhone app on iOS or a Mac app on MacOS?

Comment: This is iPad app. Here is the console log:


2011-04-11 16:36:59.784 AJiPadPhotos[5881:7203] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4e222c0 of class NSHTTPURLResponse autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-04-11 16:36:59.784 AJiPadPhotos[5881:7203] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4b41c80 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-04-11 16:36:59.785 AJiPadPhotos[5881:7203] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4e23ba0 of class NSConcreteData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Comment: @Monica, if it crashes you should get a stack trace.

Comment: @Twelve47, it doesn't even reflect the error..no stack trace nothing...any clue where the problem might be?

Comment: Is jpegFilePath valid? Has it been released already perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems in your code is that your running code in a thread without an autorelease pool but are using functions that would require one. Put the following code into the loadImageInBackground method:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// existing code

[pool drain];
```

This is probably just one of several problems. For further assistance, we need to see the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: Hello Codo,

Thank you for replying. I already have these in place, had just excluded them here for brevity. Anything else that could be done?

Comment: Yes, add the stack trace of the crash to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess : `arr` is an autoreleased object, so, sometimes it gets deallocated before your selector gets called. Try using `[arr copy]` and release it after saving it.

Comment: The withObject: parameters in the various performSelector methods are retained for you, so I don't see this as a problem.

Comment: Thank you @Marcelo but that didn't help :(
Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the EXACT same problem, but it turned out that the problem was something else: my URL was getting release prematurely. In the end this is what I did and it worked:

I made this call:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadData:) withObject:nil];
```

And this is the method:

```
// URL - (NSString) URL for file
// filePath - (NSString) save location on device
-(void)download:(NSString *)URL
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    [pool release];
}
```

So I think that your download code is correct, but there is some other variable that is getting deallocated early (possibly your path).

Hope this helps! I know the other answers on this page worked for me.